Не устанавливается Fedora
При попытке установить linux fedora на Asus zenbook 14 выдает ошибку device is active. Кто может помоч с данной ошибкой? Другие дистрибутивы выдают такую же ошибку.


Дело не в дистрибутиве, а в том, что скорее всего, вы пытаетесь поставить систему рядом или вместо Windows, а она этого сделать не дает (BitLocker, FastBoot), либо параметры вашего UEFI не позволяют произвести загрузку ОС с LiveISO.
Попробуйте сделать следующее:

Зайти в UEFI и отключить режим Secure Boot: перезапустить компьютер и нажать F2 во время загрузки, отключить опцию в соответствующем поле.
Отключите FastBoot. Нужно зайти в меню «Пуск» -> «Панель управления». В строке «Электропитание» кликните по ней. Через панель слева перейдите в «Действия кнопок питания». Щёлкните по ссылке «Изменение параметров, которые сейчас недоступны». Снимите галочку с пункта «Включить быстрый запуск (рекомендуется)» и подтвердите кнопкой «Сохранить изменения».
Отключите BitLocker:
Войдите в систему с правами администратора. Откройте «Панель управления», перейдите в раздел «Система и безопасность». Выберите пункт «Шифрование устройства» или «Шифрование диска BitLocker». Около иконки с нужным томом нажать «Отключить BitLocker». Либо, если не получается отключить BitLocker напрямую, поищите специальные программы, которые позволят это сделать.
Выделите достаточное место под новый раздел или удалите все существующие разделы на жестком диске в области памяти, куда планируете ставить Linux. В LiveISO зайдите в gparted (или через cli parted) и создайте раздел ext4 для монтирования в корень "/". В качестве размера раздела выберите все доступное место, которое планируется отвести под систему. Сами настройки оставляйте по-умолчанию. Попробуйте произвести установку в этот раздел снова.

